# How to write the UDP data which is send from another ip address into text file without lost losing any data

Tags: c#, udpclient

Actually in console.writeline i am getting all the data from UDPserver which is send from another ipaddress . While writing that transfered data into my text file somes data is missing it doesn't write so how to write that data into my textfile without lost

```
bool done = false;
private const int listenPort = 9050;
string strDestinationfileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Sample.txt";
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
FileStream fout = new FileStream(strDestinationfileName,   
                                 FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                 FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
try
{
    while (!done)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
        byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
        fout.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

        Console.WriteLine("Received broadcast from {0} :\n {1}\n",
            groupEP.ToString(),
            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that some data is missing? Please add examples of received data and written data.

Comment: maybe not all received bytes are ascii (invisible chars in your txt file) ?

Comment: @PVitt - it's UDP, an unreliable protocol.  I wouldn't be surprised if in some cases no packets at all get through

Comment: INFO server comment 2011-10-21 11:38:45.......
INFO server comment 2011-10-21 11:38:48  ....            INFO stream stop 2011-10-21 11:38:52......      INFO stream stop 2011-10-21 11:38:52......       INFO stream unpublish 2011-10-21 11:38:52...... INFO stream destroy 2011-10-21 11:38:52.................... this the message i received in command prompt but in my text file its write untill three lines the next destory and unpublish line doesnt write

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a packet-based, unreliable protocol.  It is the worst choice possible for what you want to do.

UDP packets might arrive in order, but they might also not arrive at all, or arrive out-of-order.  They might also be silently dropped if they are too large.

Use TCP: it's a stream-based protocol, where bytes arrive in the order sent, and will arrive reliably.  You can use .NET's built-in `Socket` or TCP classes for this.

(If you do need to use UDP, you'll need to invent your own packet encoding scheme and retry protocol to ensure packets arrive, and arrive in the correct order.  That is a very complex task for a beginner, and is basically what TCP does for you.  Just use TCP!)

Edit: for xixonia, since apparently pointing out a crucial flaw isn't worthwhile: Your never set `done` to `true`, so your loop never exits, and the final parts of your data are never flushed to disk.

Comment: The OP stated he was receiving all of the data he wanted when writing to the Console, but that the file did not contain that same data. This issues has nothing to do with the reliability of datagrams. More than likely, the datagram is being received in one encoding, but written to a file with another encoding, causing some loss of data.

Comment: xixonia - ASCII encoding is one character per byte, so data would not 'disappear', it would at worst appear with extra characters or malformed characters.  Even if you received random binary data you'd get one character per byte.  But, feel free to post an answer if you're confident.

Comment: @xixonia i receiving the same data but when writing it in to text file it missed some line which is send from the other side but missed line  message will display in console